# Autofill django summernote

Tags: python, django, summernote

I am submitting a form with summernote widget .

My forms.py:

```
 from django import forms
 from .models import Task,Images
 from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget

 class StudentTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
   title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 
  'form-control',' type': "text",'placeholder':'Enter Title'}))
   content = forms.CharField(widget=SummernoteWidget())


   class Meta:
     model = Task
     fields = [
        'title',
        'content',

     ]
     widgets = {
        'content': SummernoteWidget(),
    }

 def clean_object(self):
    instance = self.instance

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
 image = forms.ImageField(label='Image')
  class Meta:
    model = Images
    fields = ('image', )
```

The ImageForm is  a formset part of this Taskform and the form submission is happening successfully. I want the user to be able to edit a task if the task already exists. For this i want the summernote widget to prepopulate with the previously entered data (title,content,images).ANy way i can implement this?

In my views i have :

```
@login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
def TaskCreateView(request,pk,todo_id):
  if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('accounts:index')
  elif User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk, 
  mentor__isnull=True).exists():
    instance = get_object_or_404(Level, pk=pk)
    sweetify.error(request, 'You have not added a trainer yet')


    return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
 else  :
    instance = get_object_or_404(Level, pk=pk)
    qs = instance.todo_set.get(id=todo_id)

    todo = Task.objects.filter(todo=qs, student=request.user)
    print("TODOS",todo)
    verification = Verification.objects
    .filter(task__in=todo,is_accepted=True,is_rejected=False)
    bug=False
    for tod in todo:
      if tod.is_verified==False:
         bug=True
    if todo.exists() and verification.exists():
      messages.error(request, 'You already completed this task')
      return redirect('student:level-detail', pk=instance.id)

    elif bug==True:
     messages.error(request, 'You already completed this task')
     return redirect('student:level-detail', pk=instance.id)

form = StudentTaskForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.student = request.user
    obj.todo = qs
    obj.level = instance
    obj.save()



ImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Task,Images,
                                        form=ImageForm,min_num=0,
                                 max_num=3,  
 validate_min=True,extra=3)

if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                           instance=obj)
    if formset.is_valid():
       formset.save()

       return redirect('student:dashboard')
else:
    formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Images.objects.none())


context={
    'form': form,
    "qs": qs,
    'todo':todo,
    'formset': formset,
    'verified': verification,
 }


return render(request,'task_form.html',context)
```

Comment: Don't know this SummernoteWidget but in Django the task of populating inputs with object's data (in ModelForms) happens when you bind a form to an object's instance. You can check [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) for more information, but maybe you should add your view code so we can help you better.

Comment: ok sure @ivissani

Comment: I figured it out!THanks @ivissani